# Sudoku Solver gives Partial Solution in Python: Why?

Tags: python, sudoku

I was trying to solve the leetcode Sudoku Solver Problem ([Problem description here](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/august-leetcoding-challenge-2021/615/week-3-august-15th-august-21st/3905/)). But my code is only giving partial solution.

```
class Solution(object):
    def solveSudoku(self, board):
        """
        :type board: List[List[str]]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
        """
        def isValid(board, row, col, c):
          nRow = 3*(row//3)
          nCol = 3*(col//3)

          for i in range(9):
            #Check Row
            if board[row][i]==c:
              return False
            #Check Column
            if board[i][col]==c:
              return False
            #Check Grid
            if board[nRow+(i//3)][nCol+(i%3)]==c:
              return False
          return True


        def solve(board):
          for i in range(len(board)):
            for j in range(len(board)):
              if board[i][j]==".":
                for c in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
                  if isValid(board, i, j, c): 
                    board[i][j]=c
                    if solve(board):
                        return True
                    board[i][j]=="."
                return False
          return True
        solve(board)
        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
  board1 = [["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
            ["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
            [".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
            ["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
            ["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
            ["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
            [".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
            [".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
            [".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]

  Solution().solveSudoku(board1)
  print(board1)
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a comparison operator (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`) when resetting the value of a position:

```
board[i][j]=="."
```

should be:

```
board[i][j]="."
```

Comment: My bad! Thanks so much for the catch. I thought there are flaws with my logic and debugged there.